# while - fetch array | how to get the code of each output?

Tags: php, while-loop

I am making a system and I need to see information for each student. When I click the button, I need to know the student's code and open a page (seeStudent.php) with the student's information. Can someone help me?

```
<?php

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * from tb_coordinator inner join tb_teacher
on tb_coordinator.cd_coord = tb_teacher.cd_coord
inner join teacher_class on
tb_teacher.cd_teacher = teacher_class.cd_teacher
inner join tb_teacher on
teacher_class.cd_class = tb_class.cd_class 
inner join tb_student on
tb_class.cd_class = tb_student.cd_class
where tb_teacher.cd_cpf = '$cpf' and nm_class = '3a1'  order by cd_number asc");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $nm_student = $row['nm_student'];
    $cd_number = $row['cd_number'];
?>


<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 2%;">
    <div id="load_student">
      <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $cd_number . " - " . $nm_student;?>
       <a href="students.php" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" style="margin-left: 90%;">Get Information</button></a></li>
    </div>
</ul>

</div>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit modification in your prepared HTML. Add your required parameters to the anchor `href` which might help you to get student details from database in `seeStudent.php` page.

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 2%;">
    <div id="load_student">
        <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $cd_number . " - " . $nm_student;?>
            <a href="seeStudent.php?cd_number=<?=$cd_number?>&nm_student=<?=$nm_student?>" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" style="margin-left: 90%;">Get Information</button>
            </a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

If you click `Get Information` button, it will be taken you to `seeStudent.php` with two `$_GET` parameters (`cd_number, nm_student`).

Now the final task. In `seeStudent.php` page take the parameter from `$_GET` array and do other query to get student details from database and to display.

**seeStudent.php**

```
<?php
    $cd_number = isset($_GET['cd_number']) ? $_GET['cd_number'] : '';
    $nm_student= isset($_GET['nm_student']) ? $_GET['nm_student'] : '';

    // .... code stuff, possibly query and display
?>
```